# How to dual boot Fedora 30 along with Windows 10 in the same SSD boot drive?

Tags: linux, fedora, dual-boot, ssd, window

I have a desktop with a 1 TB hard drive and a 240 GB SSD where the SSD is my boot drive (Windows 10 is installed in it already, with GPT partition in UEFI mode) and the hard drive is just a data drive. Now I want to install Fedora 30 (Dual boot) in the same SSD. But stuck with the process as there is no video tutorial is available regarding SSD dual boot. Is it possible to dual boot in the SSD?

Comment: It should not be any different than dual booting on a regular hard drive.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Just install Fedora normally in UEFI.

Comment: SSD was not allowing much space to be partitioned for installation. Anyways I used a 3rd party software to do the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just did this exact thing yesterday...

1. Go to Windows Disk Managment and Shrink your voulme to make a new unpartitioned space. This is where your entire Fedora will go later.
2. Create a bootable USB stick with Fedora 30 installation. This is extremly simple - download tool [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/) (my suggestion), download the Fedora Live Image ISO file. And once you start Rufus, just select that ISO for the Boot selection and click START.
3. Reboot your machine and boot the USB stick
4. Click "Install Fedora to Hard drive" and follow instruction. Automatic partitioning is good enough.
5. Once it's finished, reboot and that's it. Boot loader is autmatically installed, you will be prompted to choose what to load: Fedora or Windows.
6. And that's it :)  Write if you get a problem..

Comment: Actually, there was a problem. When I tried to shrink the volume of my SSD, my windows was allowing only 10 GB of memory for installation. Anyways I used 3rd party software to make partition of 50 GB.

Comment: My laptop was configured to support both UEFI and Legacy boot, with Windows installed on UEFI, but when booting the USB key, Fedora used legacy boot. It never notified me nor asked about UEFI, so when installing, it simply "erased" the UEFI boot and Windows became unbootable. I had to manually change the BIOS setting to allow only UEFI boot and reinstall Fedora. Only then it did preserve the Windows boot.

Comment: I think @anol you may should have used a UEFI bootable stick for your Fedora installation. Rufus has that option to select when creating a bootable drive.